# Google Sign in Popup Account

Tags: android, android-fragments

There is a google Sign in Button in an app.
Now when the button is clicked it asks which account to choose to login.
What is that function that displays the alert dialogue to choose account?

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);


        mConnectionProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mConnectionProgressDialog.setMessage("Signing in...");

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Plus.API)
                .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.EMAIL))
                .build();

    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         {
            onSignInClicked();
            mConnectionProgressDialog.show();
        }

            }

    private void onSignInClicked() {
        // User clicked the sign-in button, so begin the sign-in process and automatically
        // attempt to resolve any errors that occur.
        mShouldResolve = true;
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
```